# Having difficulty linking JS to HTML. -intro level student-

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So my class assignment is to take a previous assignment and make it take the string from an HTML input field. Here is that previous assignment.

http://jsfiddle.net/ekj947kg/2/

```
var line = prompt("Enter the sentence to be turned into an acronym.");
var words = line.split(" ");
var result = "";
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i += 1) {
    result += words[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();
}
alert(result);
```

This is my first ever coding class and we are still early in. The two blocks that follow are copied from the book so I am not sure how they actually work yet. I have tried making the input field in my code (linked last) work by copying from these sections, but I just cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

The section recommends we look to this specific exercise for help, but part of the problem there is that it used 2 text files (.html & .js), while this assignment needs to be completed and saved in JSfiddle so we can just send the teacher a link.

Any advice that can help me figure it out would be GREATLY appreciated. Bare in mind though that my knowledge of the terminology is entry level, so the simpler the better. lol

Here is the exercise that we are supposed to look too.

html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <title>JavaScript Temperature Converter</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Temperature Conversion</h1>
        <p>
            <input type="text" id="temperature" />
            <input type="button" id="f_to_c" value="F to C" />
            <input type="button" id="c_to_f" value="C to F" />
        </p>
        <p id="result"></p>
        <script src="temperature.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

js

```
var report = function (celsius, fahrenheit) {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML =
        celsius + "\xb0C = " + fahrenheit + "\xb0F";
};
document.getElementById("f_to_c").onclick = function () {
    var f = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
    report((f - 32) / 1.8, f);
};
document.getElementById("c_to_f").onclick = function () {
    var c = document.getElementById("temperature").value;
    report(c, 1.8 * c + 32);
};
```

And finally, here is a link to my train wreck.
http://jsfiddle.net/ekj947kg/6/

p.s. The teacher recommended we look to stackoverflow for advice when we are having trouble.

Comment: Hello from S.Korea. Nice to meet you. :)
If you want get an answer ASAP, you must use more pinpoint title.

Comment: I strongly recommend code javascript & html seperately. It is not good for operator(I mean administrator of your web app). 
Read this. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_src.asp

Comment: You should look into onClick attribute... I'm giving you a hint since this is for homework.

Comment: I tried keeping the JS seperate, but I am not sure how to make the html section reference the javascript section in JSfiddle.

Comment: I should point out that my class hasn't covered functions yet. In fact, the book says in chapter 4 that functions will be covered in a later chapter, then immediately tells us to use the temperature conversion script that it showed in chapter 2. It's really annoying and confusing. lol

Answer (score 0):

You're really not that far off with what you linked at the end.

*Edited with more information.*
Some opinions:

1. First, always define your script type on the page. Script tags represent a block of executable code in the page and, while most of the time you will work with JavaScript as the language, there are other languages you can specify. It's important to tell the browser what type you are using. Useful link: http://mzl.la/1G1JCCh. I saw in your last link you have script tags in the body so make sure you define the language.
2. As someone mentioned, best practice is to define the JavaScript (JS) in a separate file. Though the book does this, for your Fiddle it's tough. HTML loads sequentially, so it being below your markup is proper. When I refer to markup, I am really just referring to your code. HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language and the markup is your code that defines or creates the document.
3. Also, on the Fiddle you have jQuery being loaded as a library. You don't need that for this so you can set it to "No-Library". If you leave it enabled, it won't hurt anything as it's written to not interfere with core JavaScript functionality. BUT, in a real world situation you would avoid loading unnecessary scripts for performance reasons. Also, I always recommend learning the fundamentals of a language before learning frameworks or libraries. jQuery is a  JavaScript library that simplifies complex operations. And while it makes a whole bunch of stuff easier, it's helpful to understand what it's actually doing behind the scenes.
4. As an additional note, instead of using report, try using the faithful "alert" command to see the value. You could also use "console.log" for most modern browsers. Unfortunately, IE doesn't like "console" in some older versions because it doesn't exist until Developer Tools are opened, throwing a JS error in some versions. For quick tests, alerts are in your face.

I think you'll see that you already have your value you need. After that, since you have your value, go at it like you did in your first project you linked.

It looks like you have a handle on what you are attempting, but some of us can clear things up a bit. The examples you already have, and the way the book is doing it, is by assigning an event handler to the click event of the DOM object.

You probably have figured this out already, but the "document.getElementById()" function retrieves a reference to the element, also known as a DOM object (DOM = document object model). An event handler is a function that is called, or executed, when an event occurs on the object it's assigned to. In this case, you're saying: "Whenever the click event happens on this element, call this function."  As the pmac89 pointed out, you can also use attributes to assign handlers to events.

Also, to expand on a bit mentioned in step 2, HTML loads sequentially, from the top down. That means the browser reads the code from top to bottom and executes it in order. Because of this, if you have your JavaScript block before your HTML, and you don't put in code to make the execution of the script wait until the page loads, you won't find the elements you want; they don't exist yet. That's why, in your case, it's important to put your script block after your HTML, in the body. As you progress, you will learn methods to work with this, and this is another thing jQuery simplifies.

Have a read at the following links for more technical details. Mozilla Dev Network (MDN) is a good resource:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FGuide%2FDOM%2FEvents%2FEvent_handlers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element

Comment: Any success is largely luck. lol
1. I don't know what you mean by define the script.
2. Markup? Is that the <p id="result"> bit? I don't think that was covered yet in the book, and I was only guessing that it was where the text appeared on the result section.
3. I updated my jsfiddle bookmark to automatically load JQuery when I load a blank page, does it cause problems to leave it on?

Your description of the event handlers and DOMs is helpful! Thank you!

I still haven't gotten it working, but I'm coming at it with a clear head and hopefully I can get SOMETHING working.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use jQuery? Why write all the `document.getElementById("c_to_f").onclick` stuff -- unless you love keyboarding, I guess.

You need to trap when a button called "clicker" is clicked:

```
$('#clicker').click(function(){
    var myVar = $('#phrase').val();
});
```

The above code has put the contents of the #phrase field into a variable `myVar`. Now you can do something with that variable.  Try making it alert:

```
alert(myVar);
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ekj947kg/7/)

Comment: My class has not covered JQuery yet, but I had to "dip my toe" into it for another past lesson. It seemed like something that could only add to JSfiddle, so I figured I would update my bookmark to have it pre-loaded.

Comment: In jsFiddle, you add jQuery up at top left - change `No Library (pure js)` to `jQuery 1.9.1` (best version for now). In your code, you add the jQ library just by adding this line in the `<head>` tags of your page: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Honestly, I would suggest learning the fundamentals of a language before learning a framework or library built on it. jQuery is a library built on JavaScript to simplify more complex operations. I think it would be fun for you to play with, but probably better you learn core JavaScript first. - My opinion. :)

Comment: Respectfully, I disagree with my colleague. I learned jQuery first, and have been fleshing in my js knowledge as I go. I've been productive for years.

Comment: I'm not saying you can't be productive and work with it. When troubleshooting things, it's useful to know how the whole thing works. jQuery definitely makes it quicker to get things done, but sometimes it's also overkill. I am not saying learn how to do all the complexities like animations and popups. Just have an understanding of the core. People learn different ways, though, and that's why we have differing opinions. :)